# Dynamic Resizing of Grid Using Auto with Split Preference

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to achieve the following in XAML (WPF):

1. By default, maintain a 60%-40% split for a grid with 2 horizontal elements
2. If the second element is blank (or smaller than 40%), allow the first element to take up the remaining space if it needs it
3. If the first element is blank (or smaller than 60%), allow the second element to take up the remaining space if it needs it

This feels like a "preferred width" instead of a "MaxWidth" type thing. Additionally, the first element is left aligned and the second element is right aligned.

Some things I've tried that don't work (also couldn't find if this question was answered - searches didn't result in what I wanted)

This doesn't work because it sets both to columns to a specified width:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Text="Test1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Test2" />
</Grid>
```

This doesn't work because although if both take up 100% of their spaces, it looks fine, but auto won't allow one element to overflow into the other area if a "MaxWidth" is set - I would like "MaxWidth" to almost be like a "PreferredWidth":

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                          MaxWidth="60% of the pixels"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                          MaxWidth="40% of the pixels" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Text="Test1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               TextAlignment="Right"
               Text="Test2" />
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to achieve (what seems like a relatively easy product spec) through just XAML? And if not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your exact requirements here but as a suggestion, why don't you handle the `SizeChanged` event and calculate and set the width of the columns yourself *programmatically*? XAML is a (limited) markup language after all.

Comment: That makes sense - I will give that a try and post my answer if it works, though I would think XAML has something like this built in as it feels (to me at least) like a common sizing requirement.